# Binary map in Matlab

Tags: matlab, binary, boolean

I know it is not possible to create a true binary variable in Matlab. Even 'true(8,1)' has a size of 8 bytes, instead of 8 bits. Very memory inefficient.

In Jon Bentley's Programming Pearls he poses this problem:

input: a file containing at most n positive integers, each less then n, where n = 1E7. No integer exists twice.
output: a sorted list in increasing order of input integers
constraints: At most roughly 1MB of storage available in main memory. Ample disk storage.

In the answer he claims the program should be able to solve it lightning fast using a binary map, or bit-vector. I tried to implement this bit-vector in matlab:

```
classdef binar
    properties (Access=protected)
        byteslist uint8
    end
    methods
        function obj = binar(N)
            N=ceil(N/8);
            obj.byteslist=zeros([N,1],'uint8');
        end
        function obj = setbit(obj,N,bit) %N from 0 to N-1
            v=rem(N,8)+1; %byte position [1 8]
            B = (N-v+1)/8+1; %byte nr [1 ..]
            obj.byteslist(B)=bitset(obj.byteslist(B),v,bit);
        end
        function bit = getbit(obj,N)
            v=rem(N,8)+1;
            B = (N-v)/8+1;
            bit = bitget(obj.byteslist(B),v);
        end    
    end
end
```

To my surprise setting bits is very slow. I timed this code:

```
N=1E7;
B = binar(N);
itr=1E5;
tic
for ct = 1:itr
    pos = uint32(randi([0,N-1],1));
    B = setbit(B,pos,1);
end
toc
```

From the size perspective this works fine. 'S=whos('B');S.bytes/2^20' returns 1.19MB. However it does not seem to be very fast. Running bitset 1E5 times takes 0.367s, where I would think this is literally the simplest operation you can ask of a computer.

Is there a way to make this faster in Matlab?

update: I tried with bitand, and a predeclared vector

```
obj.byte=uint8([1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128]); %declared on creation of obj
obj.byteslist(B)=bitand(obj.byteslist(B),obj.byte(v));
```

Then i tried:

```
obj.byteslist(B)=obj.byteslist(B)+obj.byte(v);
```

There is hardly a speed difference with bitset.

Comment: I believe, the bits operations in native will be much faster. So, you have to write .mex files for speed up.

Comment: Booleams are bytes even in processor level for any programming language. Its faster for a CPU to load a single byte than to load a bit, as they are hardwired for bytes. Just use what MATLAB gives you, it is the fastests thing, and the memory you need is, while 8 times higher, still pretty small for any modern computer

Comment: Why not just use [bitwise operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/bit-wise-operations.html)?

Comment: @Naveh: That's what I do. getbit setbit

Comment: @AnderBiguri: well, that depends on the problem at hand right? Jon Bentley's "Programming Pearls" starts with the so-called "bit-vector" representation of a set. I was wondering if this is possible in matlab.

Comment: Indeed it depends on the problem, but because the way computer are hardwired, it will never be faster to store bit as bits than as bytes. You must have a very big matrix, or very small memory to give the memory preference to this speed loss. There may be no way of making it faster. In the end, you are using a bunch of byte (or even double) operations just to store a bit!

Comment: You can try using `bitor` and `bitand` directly. Maybe it'll bypass some unnecessary checks in `bitget` and `bitset`.